# Add_filter when value is no variable?

Tags: functions, filters

Let's say I have an function like:

```
function cc_get_content_preview() {
    return apply_filters( 'cc_get_content_preview', get_the_excerpt(), 55 );
}
```

Here `get_the_excerpt()` is the `$value` that I can edit in an `add_filter` correct?

Question: As you can see the second parameter, in `apply_filters` (`get_the_excerpt()`), is not a variable. Is it correct that I can call this parameter through a $variable name to my liking in the `add_filter` function? Such as below `($cctoreturn)`:

```
//Set custom content preview for Aff posts
function cc_custom_content_preview($cctoreturn){
$post_id = get_the_ID();
if (is_sticky($post_id)) :
    $cctoreturn = $post_id;
endif;
    return $cctoreturn;
}
add_filter( 'cc_get_content_preview', 'cc_custom_content_preview', 20, 1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't really make sense of what you're trying to do. This code:

```
apply_filters( 'cc_get_content_preview', get_the_excerpt(), 55 );
```

Will let developers hook into the `cc_get_content_preview` hook to change the value that the `cc_get_content_preview()` function returns. When developers hook into an action or filter, they do so using a [callback function](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php). This function will receive any additional arguments passed to `apply_filters()` as parameters on the callback function.

In you specific function, that would look like this:

```
function my_callback_function( $a, $b ) {
    echo $a; // This will be the value of get_the_excerpt().
    echo $b; // This will be the number 55.
}
add_filter( 'cc_get_content_preview', 'my_callback_function', 10, 2 );
```

But it looks like you're trying to do something like JavaScript and pass the full function through? That's not going to work. You can't put functions into variables and execute them later like you can in JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks, this was what i wanted to know `echo $a; // This will be the value of get_the_excerpt().`